# LabelEncoder is not converting the strings into numericals (0,1,2)

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, xgboost

[image]I have the data like below, I need to encode the variables, but LabelEncoder is not encoding the strings

My data looks like below

```
Delivery_class
First Class
Same Day
Second Class
Standard Class

X=filtered_df.iloc[:, 1]
labelencoder_X = LabelEncoder()
X.values[:,1] = labelencoder_X.fit_transform(X.values[:,1].astype(str))
```

even after running the abovr code the strings remains same.

Please advice, I am a beginner in XGBoost

Comment: What exactly is `X.values[:, 1].astype(str)`? Can you provide a result of `print(X)`?

Comment: @Chris, attached the screenshot of X

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't assign back to `X.values`. Use `X.iloc`:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
le = LabelEncoder()
X.iloc[:, 1] = le.fit_transform(X.values[:, 1].astype(str))
```

Output:

```
   Index  Ship_Mode
0      0          0
1      1          0
2      2          1
3      3          1
4      4          0
5      5          2
```